# Is there a programmatic way to bypass memory cleaners on MIUI phones?

Tags: android

My app needs Pushy socket service to be on all the time, but the service gets killed by MIUI memory cleaner. Is there a programmatic way to bypass the memory cleaner? If not, how do you get your app to be whitelisted for autostart by default.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?